# Create Table query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I have the following SQL instruction that I am trying to run in SQL Server, but I seem to have the format wrong. Why is it not working?

```sql
CREATE TABLE Order
(
    OrderID NUMBER(11, 0) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID NUMBER(11, 0),
    OrderDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,

    CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    CONSTRAINT Order_FK1 
        FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID)
);
```

Comment: How does `customer` look like, especially what type is `customerid`?

Comment: `DEFAULT SYSDATE` are you sure you are using Microsoft SQL Server, it looks like it is Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

`Order` is a keyword that you must enclose in square brackets. 
`NUMBER` is not a data type for SQL Server, I think you need `INTEGER`.
Use `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `SYSDATE`.
For the reference to `Customers` I can't tell if the statement is right.

```
CREATE TABLE [Order]
(
 OrderID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 CustomerID INTEGER,
 OrderDate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATETIME(),
 CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
 CONSTRAINT Order_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `CustomerID` from `Customer` must be a `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
CREATE TABLE [Order]
(
 OrderID NUMERIC(11, 0) NOT NULL,
 CustomerID NUMERIC(11, 0),
 OrderDate DATE DEFAULT GETDATE(),
 CONSTRAINT Order_PK PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
 CONSTRAINT Order_FK1 FOREIGN KEY
 (CustomerID)
 REFERENCES Customer (CustomerID)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not running. I can identify that table name can not be order (being a keyword in sql) but what is the another error ?

Comment: I edited the query. Please try again, I forgot that Order is a reserved keyword and must be in square brackets.

Comment: Can you please identify error in below query too -CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PVALLEY.OrderLine_PK ON PVALLEY.ORDERLINE
(ORDERID, PRODUCTID)
LOGGING
STORAGE (
 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
 FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
 CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
 )
NOPARALLEL;
ALTER TABLE PVALLEY.ORDERLINE
 ADD CONSTRAINT OrderLine_PK
 PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID, PRODUCTID);

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PVALLEY_OrderLine_PK ON ORDERLINE (ORDERID, PRODUCTID) 
 ALTER TABLE ORDERLINE ADD CONSTRAINT OrderLine_PK PRIMARY KEY (ORDERID, PRODUCTID); Please note that ORDERID and PRODUCTID cannot be NULLs.

Comment: Actually I need to ask few questions on SQL . Can I text you ?